# Can gas price and amount of gas be automatically set by metamask, or are they required to be set via code in web3.js (EIP-1559)?

Tags: web3js, metamask, gas, eip-1559

I am using `web3.eth.Contract` to deploy a smart contract to the ropsten testnet. To interact with metamask I am using `window.ethereum`. I deploy the contract via the code below that I found on https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#id25:

```
myContract.deploy({
    data: '0x12345...',
    arguments: [123, 'My String']
})
.send({
    from: '0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567891',
    gas: 1500000,
    gasPrice: '30000000000000'
}, function(error, transactionHash){ ... })
.on('error', function(error){ ... })
.on('transactionHash', function(transactionHash){ ... })
.on('receipt', function(receipt){
   console.log(receipt.contractAddress) // contains the new contract address
})
.on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){ ... })
.then(function(newContractInstance){
    console.log(newContractInstance.options.address) // instance with the new contract address
});
```

Regarding the changes in gas that came wit EIP-1559 according to the top answer on this question: [Sending transactions after London Fork considering EIP 1559](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/106380/sending-transactions-after-london-fork-considering-eip-1559/106514) it's required to set `"maxFeePerGas"` and `"maxPriorityFeePerGas"` like in the example below:

```
{
  "gas": "0x5208", // = gasLimit
  "maxFeePerGas": "0xb2d05e00",
  "maxPriorityFeePerGas": "0xb2d05e00",
  "input": "0x",   // = data
  "nonce": "0xa",
  "to": "0xc6d5a3c98ec9073b54fa0969957bd582e8d874bf",
  "value": "0x0",
  "accessList": [],
  "chainId": "0x5"
}
```

In the example above the values for `maxPriorityFeePerGas, maxFeePerGas` are hard coded, but it would be better if metamask could suggest values on contract deployment.

Can gas price (`"maxFeePerGas" and "maxPriorityFeePerGas"`) and amount of gas be automatically set by metamask according to the ethereum network congestion at time of deploying the contract, or is it required to be set via code in web3.js?

If gas price can't be set automatically by metamask, what are the new web3.js functions to estimate `baseFeePerGas, maxPriorityFeePerGas, maxFeePerGas`.

Prior to EIP-1559 I used `web3.eth.getGasPrice()` to estimate gas.

Comment: Slaven, did you figured out how to calculate "maxFeePerGas" and "maxPriorityFeePerGas" ?

Comment: Hello! You might want to check this other answer on how to estimate the max fee and the priority fee in web3.js > https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/113373/89782